# VueJs - Using Slot name to call a component in another component

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, slot

I have a component 'ProgressCircular.vue'. I need to call this component in another component and my senior told me to use slot name.

Please help me out. Adding my progress **circular component**:

```
<template>
<div>
<v-overlay :value="true">
  <v-row justify="center" align="center">
    <div class="text-center ma-12">
      <v-progress-circular
        
        :rotate="rotate"
        :size="size"
        :value="value"
        :width="width"
        color="red"
      indeterminate ></v-progress-circular>
    </div>
  </v-row>
</v-overlay>
</div>
</template>
<style scoped>
</style>
<script>
  export default {
    data: () => ({
      indeterminate: true,
      rotate: 0,
      size: 50,
      value: 0,
      width: 1
    }),
  }
</script>
```

Vuetify link: https://v15.vuetifyjs.com/en/components/progress

Component where i need to integrate progresscircular is given below: **DocumentComponent**

```
<template>
    <div class="components" :key="documentComponentkey">
        <!--Document Version History Component-->
        <DocumentHistoryComponents></DocumentHistoryComponents>
        <!--Generic Header Component-->
        <HeaderComponents></HeaderComponents>
        <div class="components-sub-container">                         
            <!--Generic Form Component-->
            <BodyComponents></BodyComponents>
        </div>
        <!--Generic Footer Component-->
        <FooterComponents></FooterComponents>
    </div>
</template>
```

I need to call circular progress component in DocumentComponent using slot property in Circular progress component

**Tried:**
I have modified code as below:

```
<template #circularProgress>
<div>
    <v-flex xs10 class="mx-auto progressbar">
        <v-progress-circular  :rotate="rotate || 360"
                             :size="size || 100"
                             :width="width || 7"
                             color="#557fb5"
                             :value="value || 0"
                             indeterminate v-html="value || 0">
        </v-progress-circular>
    </v-flex>
</div>
```

and my child component as:

```
 <slot :value = 'uploadPercentage' :rotate="360" :size="100">{{uploadPercentage}}</slot>
```

I am getting uploadPercentage not the circular progress bar

Comment: Although it's getting unclear what's ur exact requirement. I expect it because u r not familiar with slots in Vue. I suggest you read the docs here https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html which will give u a fair idea.

Comment: I don't think slots solve your problem. You might use slots if there is anything you want to add to your circular progress component when using it in your document component

Comment: so i have to use default slot in circular progres bar copmponent

Comment: But my senior told me i can use slot to show the circular ptogress bar in Document component. Is it possible?

Comment: is it possible to load a component inside a slot?